# Why don’t magic items seem to match their prices?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, pricing

As an example, a ring of Animal Friendship costs 10,800 gp, while right below it the ring of Blinking costs 27,000 gp, and yet while they're nearly identical as far as function, they don’t scale the same.

If I were following the [rules for creating magic items](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm), I’m assuming I’d get a cost of spell level × caster level × 1800 (for command activation). Yet those variables don't seem to give me the costs that the SRD/DMG tell me. Animal Friendship costs too much while Blinking costs less than it should.

Yet a ring of Meld into Stone costs 27,000 gp and it does match the formula I’m using and functioning just like the other two rings.

What’s going on here? Is there an error in the costs of several items or am I not getting something?

Answer (score 11):

[Erik’s answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/178060/4563) is totally correct that the guidelines are exactly that, just guidelines, and Wizards of the Coast can and often does write exceptions to them.

But I wanted to take a look at these two particular cases.

The *ring of animal friendship* has caster level 3rd, so by the guidelines it would cost 1 × 3 × 1800 gp = 5400 gp—half what it actually does. But its price is exactly right for a *2nd*-level command word spell at caster level 3rd. And since most items at CL 3rd are for 2nd-level spells—it’s the minimum for that spell level after all—I wonder if that might not have just been a mistake, someone going quickly, not double-checking *charm animal* and just assuming it was 2nd-level because of the caster level on the ring. Pure speculation on my part, though.

Meanwhile, the *ring of blinking* is caster level 7th, but its price is exactly what it would be at caster level 5th—which would be the usual (minimum) choice for a 3rd-level spell like *blink*. So perhaps again someone was assuming things were supposed to be at their minimums, and this time knew *blink* was a 3rd-level spell and didn’t double-check the actual caster level on the item. More speculation.

So, while purely speculative, I think there is plausible cause to suspect these two items in particular were simply in error.

Answer (score 4):

The table you are referring to is titled "Estimating Magic Item Gold Piece Values" and gives you (often poor) suggestions for what *new types* of magic items would cost.

These aren't rules, and for any item listed in the DMG you don't need to refer to the table for their cost. They just cost what is says behind that specific item, which might or not relate in any way to the table.

Keep in mind that the final price of any item is up to the DM, as a player you have no way to create your own items except in discussion with the DM who will set the final price based on what they deem the price should be, possibly by looking at the guidelines, but also likely by gut-feeling when people try to pull shenanigans.

Answer (score -2):

The costs listed after those items are the base price, not the creation price, which is half of the base price. So, the Ring of Animal Friendship is priced correctly, while the Ring of Blinking is under priced by half. If it were the creation costs, they would have listed the XP costs and days to create with the price. Another thing that is not mentioned in the books anywhere is that depending on the class of the creator will also increase the price of items.

Clerics, Druids, and Wizards are the base line for this and incure the lowest costs since they are trained. Sorcerers have the highest costs for high level items over all of the other classes with Bards just below them because they aren't trained for their magics. Paladins and Rangers fall in the middle ground between Bards and C/D/W because they are mostly trained for their magics but they don't ever get a high spell level.

Over the past few weeks I have been working on a crafting calculator in Excel so I can just input the specific data I want and it will calculate everything for me, and so far I have hit a wall at staff creation but I am slowly working through it.

Comment: The guidelines *also* are to determine base price, so no, *ring of animal friendship* is not priced “correctly,” that is, according to the guidelines.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. This answer says, "Another thing that is not mentioned in the books anywhere is that depending on the class of the creator will also increase the price of items," but Behind the Curtain: Magic Item Gold Piece Values says, "Since different classes get access to certain spells  at different levels, the prices for two characters to make the same item might actually be different" (*DMG* 282), so the answer's statement may not be entirely accurate. Still, thank you for participating, have fun, and good luck with your spreadsheet!